# Formating a double returned from a method in Java

Tags: java

I have a method that returns a double. When I call this method and print its result, it prints out `10.3333333` for example. I would like the method to return a something like `10.3` instead.

The method is:

```
  public double getscore() { 
      int x=0;
      double x1=0;
      for (int i=0; i<3 ;i++) {
          x+=mark[i];
      }
      x1=x/3;
      return (x1);
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    double d = 1.234567;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

[reference](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-programming-tutorials/297-how-format-double-value-2-decimal-places.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `toFixed` method:

```
return x1.toFixed(1) // Returns a string that rounds to one decimal place
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always do:

```
String.format("%.1f",doubleValue);
```

to get a String with the formatted value.

If what you want is to transform the value to a double, you can do:

```
double doubleValue = 10.333333;
doubleValue = java.lang.Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.1f",doubleValue))
//doubleValue is now 10.3
```